# How do I manage unlocking accounts in a test in Truffle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle

I have a test that exercises a contract function across different accounts. How do I unlock these accounts in the context of the test?

```
contract('MyContract', function (accounts) {

    it("should perform differently for different accounts", function (done) {

        var thisContract = MyContract.deployed();

        thisContract.addAccounts([accounts[1], accounts[2]], {from: accounts[0]} ).then(
            function (tx_id) {
              /* this works because I manual unlock acc 0 on geth */
                return thisContract.doSomething({from: accounts[0]});
            }).then(
            function (tx_id) {
              /* is there something here I can do to unlock acc 1? */
                return thisContract.doSomething({from: accounts[1]});
            }).then(
            function (tx_id) {
              /* then here... */
                return thisContract.doSomething({from: accounts[2]};
                done();
            }
        ).catch(done);

    });

});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm using testrpc and need to unlock my contract's account to test a function that sends to an address

Comment: Hi @ElliottMcNary . If you are using testrpc you do not have to unlock accounts.  On a geth node console, you do that with personal.newAccount("passphrase”) and personal.unlockAccount(address, "password").

Answer (score 4):

You cannot unlock accounts from your code. It would be an issue if a code can unlock your accounts.

It seems like you are writing unit tests. Instead of running geth, you might want to try using [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc). Accounts in testrpc do not need to be unlocked before use.

Comment: I have been using TestRPC but ran into issues because it does not truly replicate the behavior of a node itself :-) Chicken and egg.

Comment: You can also try to unlock multiple accounts on geth before you run your unit tests.

Comment: Hi uzyn,
As you cannot have someone manually unlocking your account before communicating with the smartcontract, how does current dapps platform make it work if you cannot unlock accounts from your code?
Thanks !

Comment: @fabdarice There are 2 ways to do that: 1. unlock accounts at the node (geth/parity); or 2. sign your tx at your code and only broadcast the signed tx at node.

Comment: could you maybe expand a little bit of both solutions? Sorry I'm kinda new to this. I'm personally interested in the case where any user can use your platform to make a transaction. That would require their private key and password to unlock their account, but I don't want them to feel unsafe about doing so.

Comment: If it involves user's private key then it has to be method 2 as I described. You can check out MyEtherWallet, their implementation is exactly that.